# Extract values from input fields and store in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with a few input fields containing a value:

```
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

I need Javascript/jQuery to extract these values and store them in an array like this:

```
var myArray = ["Apple", "Pear"];
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `var myArray=[$("#input_1").val(),$("#input_2").val()]` ? - why not check out the jQuery manual? this is REALLY basic stuff

Comment: ...or `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).map(x => x.value);`

Comment: Too basic! Do a little bit of reading!

Comment: Maybe I should have cleared up that I was looking for a way to automatically extract the values of all <input type="text"> elements in the DOM, no matter the name of the ID's (input_1, input_2) etc. Sorry if this question appears too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `map()` and `get()` to return array of values.

```js
var myArray = $('input[type="text"]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(myArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

Comment: A very nice and clean solution. Thanks a lot Nenad Vracar :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the input tags:

```js
var data = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i< inputs.length; i++)
{
  data.push(inputs[i].value);
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

**If you use JQuery**

```js
    var data = [];
    $('input').each(function(){
      data.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
    <input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

**Optimized JQuery:**

```js
        var data = [];
        $(":text").each(function(){ //only searches for input type="text"
          data.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

**UPDATE**

I would strongly recommend you to use a common class in all your input elements and then loop through them like `$('.the_class')` as it is even more optimised.

Comment: Works fine.Sweet!

Comment: I appreciate your update as there might be other input elements that I want to exclude from having their values extracted.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` solution.

```js
var arr = [];
$('input').each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

Or a pure js solution.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'),
    res = Array.from(elems).map(v => v.value);
    console.log(res);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
<input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
```

Comment: An answer with both jQuery and vanilla jS. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var result = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function (e) {
  return e.value
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="text" id="input_1" value="Apple">
      <input type="text" id="input_2" value="Pear">
   </body>
</html>
```